# CellForRowAtIndexPath not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a settings page and I am unsure as to how to make the Log out work. I have been told to use CellForRowAtIndexPath to make it so when I click "Log out" I can set it to actually logout using PFUser.logout()

Im sure this is a simple answer but I could not find anything remotely close to what I was looking for, does anybody have a quick solution? Thank you so much in advance.

[image]

Comment: You should add some code regarding how you create the UITableView and how you handle tap event on it.

Comment: All of the cells except the logout cell segue to different VC's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) method in the [`UITableViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/) protocol that tells the delegate that the specified row is now selected to handle the cell selected in the `UITableView` like in this way:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   // call to the PFUser.logout() here to log out the user properly
   print(indexPath.row)

}
```

I hope this help you.